# Unity project can't find the right path of database in Android device

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project which work without problems in unity editor, but when I run the app on an Android device the problem is shown.

The problem is that the app can't find the database in datapath which in the code
So, it makes a file with same name in this destination and this file is empty.
So in any method need data from database there is an error that (not find the table)

I put database in assets Folder

Here is the code to detect the path.

I tried first only this part:

```
testconnectionString = Application.dataPath + "/ARMaze.sqlite";
```

Then the hall code.
Then the code without the comment part.
And the I have the problem each time.

```
void Start()
{
    if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        testconnectionString = Application.dataPath + "/ARMaze.sqlite";
    }
    else
    {
        testconnectionString = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ARMaze.sqlite";

        //if (!File.Exists(testconnectionString))
        //{
        //    WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + "/ARMaze.sqlite");
        //    while (!load.isDone) { }

        //    File.WriteAllBytes(testconnectionString, load.bytes);
        //}
    }
       
    connectionString = "URI=file:" + testconnectionString ;
    Debug.Log("Connection String is "+connectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general for system paths you not concatenate the string directly but rather use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

```
if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)
{
    testconnectionString = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "ARMaze.sqlite");
}
else
{
    testconnectionString = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "ARMaze.sqlite");
    ...
```

It automatically uses the correct path separator (`\` or `/`) for the target platform.

I might be wrong but I think also the `!` in a system path might make trouble. Why even adding a `!/assets` here? Shouldn't it be the same path as before `testconnectionString`?